# Tomcat War Deployment Error with Logback in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, logging

I've set up logback with Spring Boot.
When I use 'mvn package', it creates the log files at the designated location specified in logback-spring.xml
Yet when I deploy the war onto Tomcat manager, I get the following error in the tomcat log files.

```
02-Jan-2023 19:36:45.008 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-100] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/springapp'
02-Jan-2023 19:36:47.131 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-100] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: Error starting [/springapp]
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springapp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        ...
        ...
        ...
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE-ROLLING] - openFile(springapp.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: springapp.log (Permission denied)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:344)
        ...
        ...
        ...
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5211)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 35 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE-ROLLING] - openFile(springapp.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: springapp.log (Permission denied)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:179)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:329)
        ... 56 more
02-Jan-2023 19:36:47.131 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-100] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost
```

Tomcat is installed at /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-version/
My log file destination is /opt/tomcat/applogs/ with permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 tomcat tomcat 4096 Dec  8 14:02 apache-tomcat-9.0.70
drwxrwxrwx 2 tomcat tomcat 4096 Jan  2 19:35 applogs
```

I've tried changing user:groups to {whoami}:{whoami}, root:root, among others, but tomcat manager won't start the war deployment

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/springapp] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springapp]]]
```

I know the logs created already are from spring boot and have nothing to do with tomcat, and I also know that tomcat requires a dedicated user for security purposes, but I'm at a loss on what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The log directory you specified has insufficient permission, and the application has no write permission。

you can use `chmod 777 dir` give that directory full access，Or specify a directory with access permission in the configuration file